# Adding several results from selects in one input

Tags: javascript, html

Good night.

I'm making a STATS Calculator for a role-playing game, but I have a problem and it's that when selecting the STATS based on 'Raza' (race) and 'Nivel' (level) in the two selections at the beginning, and then select some selections from the bottom, it doesn't add up both amounts.

For example, 'Brujas y brujos' and 'Nivel nato' give '6 Fuerza', and adding '+1 FUE' instead of '7 Fuerza' resets the count, and '1 Fuerza' appears.

```js
// stats generales por nivel
$('.raza,.nivel').on('change', function() {
  var raza = $('.raza').val();
  var nivel = $('.nivel').val();
  
  if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('6');
    $('.mag').val('10');
    $('.res').val('2');
    $('.vel').val('2');
    $('.vit').val('55');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('8');
    $('.mag').val('20');
    $('.res').val('4');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('65');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('10');
    $('.mag').val('30');
    $('.res').val('6');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('80');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('12');
    $('.mag').val('40');
    $('.res').val('8');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('90');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('7');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('3');
    $('.vel').val('2');
    $('.vit').val('50');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('9');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('5');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('60');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('11');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('7');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('70');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('13');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('9');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('85');
    } else if (raza == 'Humanos' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('7');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('2');
    $('.vel').val('1');
    $('.vit').val('35');
      } else if (raza == 'Humanos' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('9');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('4');
    $('.vel').val('2');
    $('.vit').val('45');
      } else if (raza == 'Humanos' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('11');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('6');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('55');
        } else if (raza == 'Humanos' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('13');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('8');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('65');
           } else if (raza == 'Licántropos' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('7');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('3');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('55');
             } else if (raza == 'Licántropos' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('9');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('5');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('65');
               } else if (raza == 'Licántropos' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('11');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('7');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('80');
                 
                 } else if (raza == 'Licántropos' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('13');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('9');
    $('.vel').val('6');
    $('.vit').val('90');
                   
} else if (raza == 'Sirenas y tritones' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('6');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('2');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('55');          
} else if (raza == 'Sirenas y tritones' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('8');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('4');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('65');

} else if (raza == 'Sirenas y tritones' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('10');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('6');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('80');
  
  } else if (raza == 'Sirenas y tritones' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('12');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('8');
    $('.vel').val('8');
    $('.vit').val('90');
    
 } else if (raza == 'Vampiros' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('14');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('6');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('85');
   
 } else if (raza == 'Vampiros' && nivel == 'Nivel primario') {
    $('.fue').val('18');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('8');
    $('.vel').val('6');
    $('.vit').val('100');

 } else if (raza == 'Vampiros' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('22');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('10');
    $('.vel').val('7');
    $('.vit').val('115');
   
} else if (raza == 'Vampiros' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('26');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('12');
    $('.vel').val('8');
    $('.vit').val('130');              
  } else {
    // default?
    $('.fue').val('0');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('0');
    $('.vel').val('0');
    $('.vit').val('0');
  }
});

// puntos de stats por nivel
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nivel').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value == 'Nivel nato') {
      $('.ps').val('10');
    }
    if (value == 'Nivel primario') {
      $('.ps').val('20');
    }
    if (value == 'Nivel medio') {
      $('.ps').val('30');
    }
     if (value == 'Nivel total') {
      $('.ps').val('40');
    }
    $('.ps').change();
  });
  $('.select').on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.select').each(function() {
      var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price"));
      console.log(price);
      total += price;
    });
    $("#opt_price").val(total.toFixed(0))
      .change(); // Trigger
  });

  $(".a2, .b2").on("keydown keyup change", function(event) { // <--- Respond to change event, too
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); //we will use this to restrict scope to the current table row
    tr.find(".c2").val(Number(tr.find(".a2").val()) + Number(tr.find(".b2").val()));
  });
});


// suma de stats
//fuerza
function updateFuerzaInputValue(){
  //Get the input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("fuerzaselect").value;
  
  //Update the input value in the input box
  document.getElementById("fue").value = inputValue
}

//magia
function updateMagiaInputValue(){
  //Get the input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("magiaselect").value;
  
  //Update the input value in the input box
  document.getElementById("mag").value = inputValue
}

//resistencia
function updateResistenciaInputValue(){
  //Get the input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("resistenciaselect").value;
  
  //Update the input value in the input box
  document.getElementById("res").value = inputValue
}

//velocidad
function updateVelocidadInputValue(){
  //Get the input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("velocidadselect").value;
  
  //Update the input value in the input box
  document.getElementById("vel").value = inputValue
}

//vitalidad
function updateVitalidadInputValue(){
  //Get the input value
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("vitalidadselect").value;
  
  //Update the input value in the input box
  document.getElementById("vit").value = inputValue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3fad2a3853.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"/> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css"><meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin|ABeeZee|Open+Sans|Lora:800|Great+Vibes|UnifrakturCook:700|UnifrakturMaguntia&display=swap" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,400,500,700|Old+Standard+TT:400,700|Poppins:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Condensed:400,700&display=swap"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bai+Jamjuree:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Cormorant+Infant:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Cormorant+SC:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Encode+Sans+Expanded:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Karla:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Nunito+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Rubik:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Slabo+27px:300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Source+Sans+Pro&display:300,400,500,600,700,800,900=swap"/> 

<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"> 
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css"><meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<form method="POST" action="035-ejemplo-atributos-min-max-html5.php" name="formu" class="formu"><div class="imggene">
    <div class="titlegene">
        Calculadora de STATS 
    </div>
</div>
    <div style="" class="row"><div style="font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;text-transform: uppercase;background: #121212;border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;outline: 1px solid #0A0A0A; border-top: 1px solid #0a0a0a; outline-offset: -20px;border: 20px solid #181818;box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0A0A0A;height: 69px;"><div style="padding: 10px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;text-transform: uppercase;color: #8A8A8A;font-family: source code pro;font-size: 11px;text-align: center;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;"><table><tbody><tr><td><div style="height: 40px;width: 40px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-chess" style="font-size: 15px"></i></span></div><div style="height: 40px;width: 255px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 40px;"><select  name="titulos" class="raza" style="max-width: 390px!important; border: none; padding: 10px 90px 10px 0px;"><option hidden value="" disabled selected>Raza</option><option label="Brujas y brujos">Brujas y brujos</option>
  <option label="Hijos de Eva">Hijos de Eva</option>
    <option label="Humanos">Humanos</option>
    <option label="Licántropos">Licántropos</option>
  <option label="Sirenas y tritones">Sirenas y tritones</option>
     <option label="Vampiros">Vampiros</option>
  </select></div></td><td><div style="height: 40px;width: 40px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-flag" style="font-size: 15px"></i></span></div><div style="height: 40px;width: 255px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 40px;"><select  name="titulos" class="nivel" style="max-width: 390px!important; border: none; padding: 10px 90px 10px 0px;"><option hidden value="" disabled selected>Nivel</option><option label="Nivel nato">Nivel nato</option>
  <option label="Nivel primario">Nivel primario</option>
    <option label="Nivel medio">Nivel medio</option>
    <option label="Nivel total">Nivel total</option>
  </select></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
    
        <div style="padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #0a0a0a; text-transform: uppercase; background: #111; border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;"><table style=" display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; "><tbody><tr><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="fue" type="text" class="fue" value="" placeholder="0"> Fuerza</div></td><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="mag" type="text" class="mag" value="" placeholder="0"> Magia</div></td><td><div class="stats"><input id="res" type="text" class="res" value="" placeholder="0"> Resistencia</div></td><td><div class="stats" style="width: 120px;"><input id="vel" type="text" class="vel" value="" placeholder="0"> Velocidad</div></td><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 115px; "><input id="vit" type="text" class="vit" value="" placeholder="0"> Vitalidad</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
          
    <div style="display: none"><input type="number" name="edad" placeholder="Edad" id="edad"/></div>
    
<div style="font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;text-transform: uppercase;background: #121212;border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;outline: 1px solid #0A0A0A;border-top: 1px solid #0a0a0a;outline-offset: -15px;border: 15px solid #181818;box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0A0A0A;"><table style="
    padding: 5px;
"><tbody><tr><td><div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-fist-raised" style="font-size: 15px"></i></div><div style="height: 30px;width: 95px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 30px;"><select class="select fuerza" id="fuerzaselect" onchange="updateFuerzaInputValue()" style="
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
">
<option hidden="" disabled="" selected="" data-price="0" value="Fuerza">Fuerza</option>
<option data-price="0" value="0">0</option>
<option data-price="-2" value="1">+1 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-4" value="2">+2 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-6" value="3">+3 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-8" value="4">+4 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-10" value="5">+5 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-12" value="6">+6 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-14" value="7">+7 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-16" value="8">+8 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-18" value="9">+9 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-20" value="10">+10 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-22" value="11">+11 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-24" value="12">+12 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-26" value="13">+13 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-28" value="14">+14 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-30" value="15">+15 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-32" value="16">+16 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-34" value="17">+17 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-36" value="18">+18 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-38" value="19">+19 FUE</option>
<option data-price="-40" value="20">+20 FUE</option>
</select></div></td><td><div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-hand-sparkles" style="font-size: 15px"></i></div><div style="height: 30px;width: 95px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 30px;"><select class="select magia" id="magiaselect" onchange="updateMagiaInputValue()" style="
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
">
<option hidden="" disabled="" selected="" data-price="0" value="Magia">Magia</option>
<option data-price="0" value="0">0</option>
<option data-price="-2" value="1">+1 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-4" value="2">+2 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-6" value="3">+3 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-8" value="4">+4 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-10" value="5">+5 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-12" value="6">+6 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-14" value="7">+7 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-16" value="8">+8 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-18" value="9">+9 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-20" value="10">+10 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-22" value="11">+11 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-24" value="12">+12 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-26" value="13">+13 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-28" value="14">+14 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-30" value="15">+15 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-32" value="16">+16 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-34" value="17">+17 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-36" value="18">+18 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-38" value="19">+19 MAG</option>
<option data-price="-40" value="20">+20 MAG</option></select></div></td><td><div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-shield-alt" style="font-size: 15px"></i></div><div style="height: 30px;width: 117px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 30px;"><select class="select resistencia" id="resistenciaselect" onchange="updateResistenciaInputValue()" style="
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
">
<option hidden="" disabled="" selected="" data-price="0" value="Resistencia">Resistencia</option>
<option data-price="0" value="0">0</option>
<option data-price="-5" value="1">+1 RES</option>
<option data-price="-10" value="2">+2 RES</option>
<option data-price="-15" value="3">+3 RES</option>
<option data-price="-20" value="4">+4 RES</option>
<option data-price="-25" value="5">+5 RES</option></select></div></td><td><div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-running" style="font-size: 15px"></i></div><div style="height: 30px;width: 106px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 30px;"><select class="select velocidad" id="velocidadselect" onchange="updateVelocidadInputValue()" style="
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
">
<option hidden="" disabled="" selected="" data-price="0" value="Velocidad">Velocidad</option>
<option data-price="0" value="0">0</option>
<option data-price="-5" value="1">+1 VEL</option>
<option data-price="-10" value="2">+2 VEL</option>
<option data-price="-15" value="3">+3 VEL</option>
<option data-price="-20" value="4">+4 VEL</option>
<option data-price="-25" value="5">+5 VEL</option></select></div></td><td><div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: #151515;border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px 1px #0A0A0A, 1px -1px 0 #0A0A0A, -1px -1px #0A0A0A;color: #352534;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;float: left;"><i class="fas fa-heart" style="font-size: 15px"></i></div><div style="height: 30px;width: 106px;text-transform: uppercase;border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;background: #111;font-weight: 700;text-align: center;line-height: 30px;"><select class="select vitalidad" id="vitalidadselect" onchange="updateVitalidadInputValue()" style="
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
">
<option hidden="" disabled="" selected="" data-price="0" value="Vitalidad">Vitalidad</option>
<option data-price="0" value="0">0</option>
<option data-price="-1" value="5">+5 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-2" value="10">+10 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-3" value="15">+15 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-4" value="20">+20 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-5" value="25">+25 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-6" value="30">+30 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-7" value="35">+35 VIT</option>
<option data-price="-8" value="40">+40 VIT</option></select></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>

<div class="puntosrasgos"><div class="col-six" style="
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
"><div class="titulopuntosrasgos">Puntos de STATS</div></div><div class="col-four"><div class="input-group" style="
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -23px;
    margin-left: 145px;
">
<table style="">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="10" rowspan="1" style="
    table-layout: fixed;
    min-width: 35px;
"><div class="col-pp"><input class="col-xs-4 a2 ps" type="number" disabled id="form-field-first"  value="0" name="positivos" style="max-width: 30px; background: #111; border: 1px solid #111"></div></td>
<td width="10" rowspan="1"><div class="col-pp"><input class="col-xs-4 b2" value="0" type="number" disabled id="opt_price" placeholder="0" name="negativos" style="max-width: 30px; background: #111; border: 1px solid #111"></div>
</td>
<td colspan="3" height="10"><div class="col-pp"><input class="col-xs-4 c2" value="0" type="number" disabled id="form-field-first" placeholder="0" name="total" style="max-width: 30px; background: #111; border: 1px solid #111"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></div></div></div></div>
```

What could I do?

Comment: As far as I can see, your `update...()` functions just overwrite; there is no attempt to add to the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do the changes and calculations is very difficult to use and prone to errors like youre experiencing. I would suggest rewriting it to use objects with values for each race and level so you can use real numbers in your calculations, without having to do anything manually:

```js
// Object with all races and levels
const stats = {
    // Create object for each race
    brujas: {
         // An array of values for each level for each stat
        fue: [6,  8,  10, 12],
        mag: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        res: [2,  4,  6 , 8],
        vel: [2,  3,  4 , 5],
        vit: [55, 65, 80, 90],
    },
    // ...
};
```

Then instead of having a long list of `if/else` (which would grow exponentially if you add more races or levels), you just have to get stats from that race and level:

```js
$('.raza,.nivel').on('change', function() {
    const raza = $('.raza').val(); // Should return a key for the race, like 'brujas'
    const nivel = $('.nivel').val(); // Should return an index for the level, like '0'
    const stat = stats[raza]; // Get the race from stats

    // Set all stat values
    $('.fue').val(stat.fue[nivel]);
    $('.mag').val(stat.mag[nivel]);
    $('.res').val(stat.res[nivel]);
    $('.vel').val(stat.vel[nivel]);
    $('.vit').val(stat.vit[nivel]);
});
```

Which you can do by changing your `selects` (see their options values):

```html
<select class="raza">
    <option value="brujas">Brujas y brujos</option>
    ...
</select>

<select class="nivel">
    <option value="0">Nivel nato</option>
    <option value="1">Nivel primario</option>
    <option value="2">Nivel medio</option>
    <option value="3">Nivel total</option>
</select>
```

This isnt a direct answer to your question, but by changing the logic youll hopefully be able to do any calculation in an easier way, which might just get rid of the problem youre having.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to find out some way in which I can keep the previous value when entering the new value without overwriting it.